# How to secure my secretKey that i use for encrypting data?

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption, android-security

New to this field
Can anyone help me with it?

I've tried storing it in build.gradle file,

```
buildConfigField "String", "secretKey", "\"$key\""    //$key contains key
```

but got an alert from play console after publishing it.

> Security alert

> Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns.

Comment: please include HOW you're storing it as an example for others, making sure you don't include the actual key :)

Comment: Updated, Would you please check @a_local_nobody